# No able to connect to spark cluster via sparklyr package when my custom package method is invoked via OpenCpu

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, sparklyr, opencpu

I have created an R package that makes use of the `sparklyr` capabilities within a dummy hello function. My package does a very simple thing as connection to a spark cluster, print the spark version and disconnect. The package is successfully clean and build and is successfully executed from R and `Rstudio`.

```
# Connect to Spark cluster
  spark_conn <-  sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "spark://elenipc.home:7077", spark_home = '/home/eleni/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/')

# Print the version of Spark
  sv<- sparklyr::spark_version(spark_conn)
  print(sv)

  # Disconnect from Spark
  sparklyr::spark_disconnect(spark_conn)
```

It is very important for me to be able to execute the hello function from `OpenCpu` rest api. (I have used `opencpu` api for executing many other custom created packages.) 
When invoking `opencpu` api like:

```
curl http://localhost/ocpu/user/rstudio/library/myFirstBigDataPackage/R/hello/print -X POST
```

i get the following response:

```
Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (89615): Gateway in port (8880) did not respond.
Path: /home/eleni/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit
Parameters: --class, sparklyr.Shell, '/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-2.2-2.11.jar', 8880, 89615
Log: /tmp/ocpu-temp/file26b165c92166_spark.log


---- Output Log ----
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes

---- Error Log ----

In call:
force(code)
```

Of course allocate more memory to both java & spark executor does not resolve the issue. permission issues are also discarded as i already configured the `etc/apparmor.d/opencpu.d/custom` file so as to permit `opencpu` to have rwx privileges on spark. It seems to be a connectivity issue that i do not know how to face. During method invocation via opencpu api spark logs do not even print something.

For you info my environment configuration is as follows:

- java version "1.8.0_65"
- R version 3.4.1
- RStudio version 1.0.153
- spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
- opencpu 1.5  (compatible with my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)

Thank you very much for you support and time!!!

Comment: Is there any way you can upgrade to a more recent version of OpenCPU? We fixed quite a bunch of issues in the 2.0 branch.

Comment: my linux version Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) does not support opencpu-2.0 that is supported by Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), but i will set up quickly a vm to test it

Comment: @Jeroen I installed all from scratch to a fresh ubuntu vm 16.04 with opencpu-2.0. The message is the same with a more verbose output log.    
`---- Output Log ----
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# pthread_getattr_np
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/ocpu-temp/ocpu_session_688dfe5843/hs_err_pid1684.log
[thread 140374552274688 also had an error]``

Comment: As of opencpu 2.0.4 the `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` file has a new option `enable.rlimits`. Can you try changing that to `false` and then `apachectl restart`?

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks a lot for your help!!! A fresh installation again resolved the issue!! opencpu is amazing and you very helpfull!